# Angular - getting values from Http get (backend) to APP_BASE_HREF

Tags: angular

I have an app where I have locale as prefix.

I did that by some crappy logic with recognizing the locale by pattern, replace that locale when needed etc. but this logic is really hard to maintain and to do any changes around that logic - its ultra easy to break anything... especially with routing.

So I wanted to change that logic into solution with setting APP_BASE_HREF as locale.

To do that I need to at the very beginning get the values from the backend by http get which are:

- List of countries along with locale etc. allowed in App
- Geolocation based on IP

Then by that I'm establishing the country, where priority is given to:

1. Url
2. Saved Country in local storage
3. Geolocation based on IP
4. Browser language

I've got service for APP_INITIALIZER where I'm getting all environment variables but APP_INITIALIZER is initialized by APP_BASE_HREF and there is no way to wait for response from backend in APP_BASE_HREF

Is there any way to initiate the call for config before APP_BASE_HREF?

So far I didn't find any solution since 2 days.

Comment: Set `APP_BASE_HREF` as empty string initially. Then fetch values from backend from a service. Add this service before `APP_INITIALIZER` provider. After getting values, change  `APP_BASE_HREF` based on locale.

Comment: @Nikhil I think that there is no way to do backend call before APP_INITIALIZER (and even if there was such a thing, it is already after APP_BASE_HREF), with your suggestion I can resolve Locale in service after or directly into APP_INITIALIZER and do something like window.reload() but this is more like a "cheat' than a real solution.